# Using For-loops to get integers from user, then printing the even numbers

Tags: java

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class evenArray
{//begin class
public static void main(String[]args)
{//begin main method
  java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println();

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of intergers you want to put into the array.");
  int numbers = input.nextInt();
  int[] arrayInt = new int[numbers];
  int i = 0;

  System.out.println("Please enter the numbers to enter into the array.");
  for (i =1; i < arrayInt.length; i++){
      arrayInt[i] = input.nextInt();
      }

  int evenNumber = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++){
     if(arrayInt[i] % 2 == 0){
     evenNumber++;
     System.out.println("The even numbers are " + evenNumber); 
     }
  }

 }

 }
```

It compiles fine, but this is what prints:

dhh005@cs:~$ java evenArray

```
Please enter the number of intergers you want to put into the array.
6
Please enter the numbers to enter into the array.
10
 -7 
3
42
-20
The even numbers are 1
The even numbers are 2
The even numbers are 3
The even numbers are 4
```

I cant figure out why it isn't showing the actual even numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Variable names can be confusing. Try renaming your variables so they better reflect their value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println("The even numbers are " + evenNumber);
```

with

```
System.out.println("The even numbers are " + arrayInt[i]);
```

And you can remove the `evenNumber` variable altogether.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `evenNumber` instead of `arrayInt[i]`. `evenNumber` is just storing the count, whereas `arrayInt[i]` has the even number you want to print. All you would need to do is replace that, and it will print out the even numbers instead of the count of even numbers you currently have.